# Laravel 5.6: Reset password link broken?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am writing the functionality for the Forgot Password of my app and can see my `password_resets` populated:

```
CREATE TABLE `password_resets` (
  `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `password_resets_email_index` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

with:

```
ts@test.tes $2y$10$yv1qGOxvamSEmdteK6NNUuDnHmhKUjFQyJBHtOxeYwRiqGSWr936O    2018-04-09 14:03:32
```

In my ResetPasswordController@reset(Request $request) I have:

```
 $token = \DB::table('password_resets')->where('token',$request->_token)->first();
```

also, when I try to do it manually by using the following bit it fails again as the token in `password_resets` table is hashed:

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

**Update**

```
/**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            dd('FAILED');
        }
```

$token = \DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $request->get('_token'))->first();
    dd($token);

```
        $message = [
            'title' => trans('passwords.resetTitleSuccess'),
            'description' => trans('passwords.reset'),
            'status' => 'success',
        ];

        return redirect($this->redirectTo)->with('message', $message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try the following:

Pass the email with the URL and

Instead of

```
$token = \DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $request->get('_token'))->first()
```

Do this

```
$reset = DB::table("password_resets")->where('email', $request->email)->firstOrFail();
if(!$this->hasher->check($request->token, $reset->token))
```

Your answer is in the error message. Laravel is looking for the `_token` column in your database and your column is named `token`. Change your input name to `token` and call `$request->token` to access it.

Comment: Issue here is that it is searching for a token in `users` table whereas it should be happening in the `password_resets` table

Comment: Can you post the full code for ResetPasswordController@reset(Request $request)

Comment: So, issue is that `$request->get('_token')` is not hashed and that means that the SQL query will never succeed like this.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible that $this->validator($request->all()) is looking for '_token' in the users table? This would throw an SQL error before anything else

Comment: When you use $request->all() laravel will map input names to db columns

Comment: In this case I would see `FAILED` because of my dd('FAILED') at the beginining

Comment: Unless SQL throws an error. $validator->fails() will only work if your data was validated as incorrect. If SQL throws an error this will be output.

Comment: Can you post your validator code, I'm sure that's where the issue is

Comment: protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            '_token' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:255',
        ]);
    }

Comment: Here you are, John.

Comment: Updated my answer